# Syntax for rspec expect for find_by with an sort_by clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec

Using rspec, I would like to write an expectation that the following:

```
@clients = Client.find_all_by_status('active').sort_by {|client|client['name'].downcase}
```

Is called correctly.

```
@client = stub_client({ :name => 'abc' })
Client.should_receive(:find_all_by_status).with('active').and_return([@client])
```

This works but doesn't test that the sort_by clause is called.

Is there a syntax that will verify that the calls to `find_all_by_status` is followed by the `sort_by`)?

Comment: Please use the `{}` button for code formatting.

Comment: `where(status: 'active').order(:name)` is probably what you want here anyway. Testing that particular methods are called is an anti-pattern fro testing, you're getting way too hung up on how the result is achieved. Instead, verify the correct result is produced, ignoring how that was achieved.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to write two expectations:

```
Client.should_receive(:find_all_by_status).with('active').and_return([@client])
Client.should_receive(:sort_by)
```

Also I second the earlier comment about using order instead of sort_by for performance reasons.